# How to select completions using H,J,K,L in Vim w/ autocomplpop?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I've been using 60% keyboard for a while now. It does not have individual arrow keys (just only via modifier).
I'm a heavy user of autocomplpop (autocomplete plugin for Vim) and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to select completions from autocomplete menu other way then by pressing arrow keys.

Using CTRL+H/J/K/L produces weird results.

Comment: Its `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` by default. You can check if the menu is up with `pumvisible()`. With that you should be able to create a mapping.

Comment: Thanks! So useful, I'm basically reaching for arrow keys only to do this. Now I can forget them all together! The default mapping is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As printable characters are appended to the completion base and thereby further reduce the list of completion candidates, it's a bad idea to use those for selection in the popup completion menu.

However, Vim has `<C-N>` / `<C-P>` commands for selection in the popup menu (cp. `:help popupmenu-completion`); the cursor keys are only secondary alternatives.

If you would like to add other selection keys (preferably non-printable ones, e.g. involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), you can define such via `:imap <expr>` and the help of the `pumvisible()` function.